# I need help identifying used MTB tire sealant

Tags: mountain-bike, sealant

I have a new-used MTB and I don't know what kind of sealant is in its tires. Does anyone know what this may be, or have a good resource for figuring it out?

The liquid sealant in the tire is a light brown, like coffee with milk. The dried sealant is a slightly darker brown.

[image: Liquid sealant in tire, light brown]

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  I've never used tire sealant, but assuming the make matters, what is the brand of bike?  If it's the OEM product it might be possible to tell from the original specs.  Although I suspect it doesn't really matter that much...

Comment: That’s a good point, they’re Continental tires so RevoSealant may be a good guess. It’s a Specialized Stumpjumper, I’ll try to see if they have a standard sealant they use.

Comment: Why do you need to know? You don't need to use the exact same sealant when remounting the tires. It's likely contaminated with something that affected the color.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus, I was under the impression that if different sealants are combined they may react with each other (in undesirable ways). Although I couldn't find much discussion about putting new sealant on top of dry sealant.

Comment: Just clean out the tire with paper towels and a bit of elbow grease and put new sealant in.

Comment: @nate clean out the old stuff, use fresh sealant if your choice. Isopropyl alcohol works to remove the dried bits.

Comment: looks like dirty sealant.

Comment: Ok, I'll try cleaning the insides with isopropyl alcohol as recommended by @ArgentiApparatus and then use the Stan's sealant that I've already got. Christmas is slowing me down on this now, but assuming that works I'll follow up with the answer, as y'all have suggested, being "don't worry about it, clean it good and pick a sealant". Thanks all.

Comment: @nate new sealant in old sealant works okay, provided they're the same thing.  I'm reading that the question is about identifying brand by its physical attributes, which seems impossible.

Comment: FWIW, that looks like goat head sealent.

Answer (score 2):

The final result was "don't do that" (where "that" was to try to identify and match the existing sealant). Per advice in the comments I cleaned out the remaining liquid sealant (and the crud where the sealant had pooled and hardened during non-use), cleaned the inside with isopropyl alcohol and a lint-free towel, and then set the tires up with the sealant I have on hand (Stans). They have been holding pressure and riding great.

Answer (score -2):

The tyre manufacturer would hopefully recommend a sealant for use with their tyres - that's the case with my tubeless tyres.

Looking up the brand & model is probably a good place to start.